Django dos campos en una relacion ForeignKey
Tengo una tabla de empleados con una relación ForeignKey con la tabla departamento.
Un empleado pertenece a un departamento, un departamento tiene un responsable que es un empleado.
class Empleado(models.Model):
    ''' Modelo base de datos Empleado '''
    nombre = models.CharField(("Nombre"), max_length=20)
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(
        "Departamento",
        verbose_name=("Departamento"),
    )

class Departamento(models.Model):
    ''' Modelo base de datos Departamento '''
    departamento = models.CharField(("Departamento"), max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.departamento)

No puedo crear este campo en Departamento:
responsable = models.ForeignKey("Empleado",verbose_name=("Responsable"))

Quiero añadir en el departamento un campo que un empleado es el responsable de ese departamento
Tabla Empleado
Empleado,Departamento

Victor,Direccion
Paco,Informatica
Juan,Informatica
Luis,Obras
Andres,Obras

Tabla Departamento:
Departamento,Responsable

Direccion,Victor
Informatica,Juan
Obras, Victor

Aunque en Departamento no existe ninguna foreingkey no puedo crearla.
¿Existe alguna solución?
Pero me da un error de ya existe una relación entre esas tablas y no puedo crear otra foreingkey a la misma tabla que ya existe.
¿Existe alguna solución?
